# Stored Procedure return values by comparison of 2 fields

Tags: c#, sql, database, stored-procedures

I have a table that contains 3 columns `USERID`, `OLDPASSWORD`, `NEWPASSWORD`.

I want to select `OLDPASSWORD` and `NEWPASSWORD` columns by `USERID` and compare `OLDPASSWORD` and `NEWPASSWORD`, if there is an equality between `NEWPASSWORD` and `OLDPASSWORD`, It should return `NEWPASSWORD`, otherwise it returns 0 (string);

Someting like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_PASSWORD]
(
    @USERID NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
     SELECT OLDPASSWORD, NEWPASSWORD 
     FROM PASSWORDINFO 
     WHERE USERID = @USERID

     IF OLDPASSWORD == NEWPASSWORD 
        RETURN "0" 
     ELSE 
        RETURN NEWPASSWORD
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using the CASE WHEN statement ?

Comment: @Robert Harvey i think he wants to compare the old and new password and returns the compariosn result..

Answer (score 1):

`Return` keyword is not designed for returning values from table. `Return` keyword is for returning from stored procedure and it can return only integer values. Here you can return some code result of executing your proc. You should directly do this with `select` statement or by having some `output parameter`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_PASSWORD] @USERID NVARCHAR(50)
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT  CASE WHEN OLDPASSWORD = NEWPASSWORD THEN '0'
                     ELSE NEWPASSWORD
                END AS CurrentPassword
        FROM    PASSWORDINFO
        WHERE   USERID = @USERID
    END
```

Or:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_PASSWORD]
    @USERID NVARCHAR(50) ,
    @CurrentPassword NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @CurrentPassword = CASE WHEN OLDPASSWORD = NEWPASSWORD
                                        THEN '0'
                                        ELSE NEWPASSWORD
                                   END
        FROM    PASSWORDINFO
        WHERE   USERID = @USERID
    END
```

Comment: This is more efficient solution to do this. Less code, do more. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_PASSWORD]
(
    @USERID NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN OLDPASSWORD = NEWPASSWORD THEN '0'
            ELSE NEWPASSWORD
         END
    FROM PASSWORDINFO
    WHERE USERID = @USERID

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like that:

```
   SELECT CASE WHEN OLDPASSWORD = NEWPASSWORD THEN '0' 
   ELSE NEWPASSWORD END AS Result 
   FROM PASSWORDINFO WHERE USERID = @USERID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_PASSWORD] (@USERID NVARCHAR(50), @result VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT @result = CASE 
            WHEN OLDPASSWORD = NEWPASSWORD
                THEN '1'
            ELSE '0'
            END
    FROM PASSWORDINFO
    WHERE UserId = @USERID
END
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, to return more than one value using return values, where as output parameters, can return any datatype and an sp can have more than one output parameters. I always prefer, using output parameters, over RETURN values.

In general, RETURN values are used to indicate success or failure of stored procedure, especially when we are dealing with nested stored procedures.Return a value of 0, indicates success, and any nonzero value indicates failure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_PASSWORD]
    @USERID NVARCHAR(50) ,
    @Password NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @Password  = CASE WHEN OLDPASSWORD = NEWPASSWORD
                                THEN '0'
                                  ELSE NEWPASSWORD
                                END
        FROM    PASSWORDINFO
        WHERE   USERID = @USERID
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_PASSWORD]
(
    @USERID NVARCHAR(50)
)
AS
    declare   @NewPassword NVARCHAR(50)
     declare   @OldPassword NVARCHAR(50)

     SELECT  @OldPassword =OLDPASSWORD, @NewPassword = NEWPASSWORD 
     FROM PASSWORDINFO 
     WHERE USERID = @USERID    

     IF @OldPassword = @NewPassword 
        RETURN "0" 
     ELSE 
        RETURN @NewPassword
```